# How to correct my first spring boot POM

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

The POM.xml is like something like i have pasted below. I have tried the oracle dependency that also have some problem.
I do not understand what are the differences between 
    normal POM and spring boot POM. I came to know it have a `<parent>`
 to resolve version conflict. Apart from that what mistakes are there in my POM i need to know

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.Microservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>Microservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Microservice</name>
    <description>Microservice for user registration</description>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <springframework.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springsecurity.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <jackson.version>2.7.5</jackson.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>Microservice</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>/Microservice</path>
                        <port>8080</port>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>controller.SampleController</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

on maven build with goal install

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Microservice 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Microservice ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ Microservice ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to E:\maven\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.102 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-04T22:26:43+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/24M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project Microservice: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\..\lib\tools.jar
[ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
[ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
[ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
[ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Please explain me the error and way to solve it.

I have included the snapshot of my environment variable

[image: I have included the snapshot of my environment variable]

Comment: make sure `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly on your machine. You have specified `1.7` jdk to be used to build in plugins(`maven-compiler-plugin`) just to cross check.

Comment: But i checked it. Should i include upto bin

Comment: yes. In your system variables  -> `path` -> add JAVA_HOME/bin.

Comment: This is my path variable C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;

Comment: What is present at `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`? If there are some jre files in that location; try removing this from your path variable

Comment: I have removed that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a pom issue. Change your environment variable JAVA_HOME to point to a jdk directory rather than jre.

Comment: I have included the snapshot of environment variables

Comment: You also need to add %JAVA_HOME%\bin in your `path` environment variable

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that you tried to compile java classes with a Java Runtime Environment (JRE). You need a Java Development Kit (JDK) to compile java classes.

Solution: Install a JDK and change to JAVA_HOME enviroment variable to the JDK directory.

Answer (score 0):

Finally two steps helped me

1) Build path---> Removing the JRE library and adding new with properties
      Standard VM
      Location

2) Added in POM.xml

```
<executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\javac</executable>    
<fork>true</fork>
```